# Problems with detecting the Y position in javascript

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

i'm working on code that will run a animation based on the Y location of the page. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be running each location within the function.  I feel like i'm not doing something correctly with my code.

```
var userHasScrolled = false;

    //this runs if the user has scrolled        
    window.onscroll=scroll;


    setInterval(function()
    {
    if (userHasScrolled == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("faux-braid-gif").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
        document.getElementById("faux-braid-gif").style.AnimationPlayState = "paused";

        document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
        document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif").style.AnimationPlayState = "paused";
    }
    }, 300);

    function scroll(ev){
        //alert("Hey!");
        userHasScrolled = true;

        if(window.pageYOffset>3000)
        {
            alert('We have reached 3000!');

            setInterval(function()
            {    
                if(userHasScrolled) {
                    //alert("Hello!");
                    document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif-Second").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
                    document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif-Second").style.AnimationPlayState = "running";

                    userHasScrolled = false;
                }
            }, 100);
        }

        else if(window.pageYOffset>2000)
        {
            setInterval(function()
            {
            //alert("I am an alert box!");
                if(userHasScrolled) {
                    //alert("Hello!");
                    //alert("I am an alert box!");
                    document.getElementById("faux-braid-gif").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
                    document.getElementById("faux-braid-gif").style.AnimationPlayState = "running";

                    userHasScrolled = false;
                }
            }, 100);
        }

        else if(window.pageYOffset>1500)
        {
            setInterval(function()
            {    
                if(userHasScrolled) {
                    //alert("Hello!");
                    document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
                    document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif").style.AnimationPlayState = "running";

                    userHasScrolled = false;
                }
            }, 100);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which of parts of your function doesn't running? Maybe problems appears because you did not call `clearInterval()` ?

Try something like this:

```
    var userHasScrolled = false;

    //this runs if the user has scrolled        
    window.onscroll=scroll;


    var intervalId = setInterval(function()
    {
    if (userHasScrolled == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("faux-braid-gif").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
        document.getElementById("faux-braid-gif").style.AnimationPlayState = "paused";

        document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
        document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif").style.AnimationPlayState = "paused";
    }
    }, 300);

    function scroll(ev){
        //alert("Hey!");
        userHasScrolled = true;

        if(window.pageYOffset>3000)
        {
            alert('We have reached 3000!');

            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = setInterval(function()
            {    
                if(userHasScrolled) {
                    //alert("Hello!");
                    document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif-Second").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
                    document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif-Second").style.AnimationPlayState = "running";

                    userHasScrolled = false;
                }
            }, 100);
        }

        else if(window.pageYOffset>2000)
        {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = setInterval(function()
            {
            //alert("I am an alert box!");
                if(userHasScrolled) {
                    //alert("Hello!");
                    //alert("I am an alert box!");
                    document.getElementById("faux-braid-gif").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
                    document.getElementById("faux-braid-gif").style.AnimationPlayState = "running";

                    userHasScrolled = false;
                }
            }, 100);
        }

        else if(window.pageYOffset>1500)
        {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = setInterval(function()
            {    
                if(userHasScrolled) {
                    //alert("Hello!");
                    document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
                    document.getElementById("topBraidOne-faux-gif").style.AnimationPlayState = "running";

                    userHasScrolled = false;
                }
            }, 100);
        }

    }
```

More information about `clearInterval()` you can find for example on [w3schools documentation page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: Its animating when I stop scrolling now which it shouldn't be doing. You can see it in action at thr33fold.com/wordpress

Comment: Hm I can't find elements with id `"topBraidOne-faux-gif-Second"` or `faux-braid-gif` on your site, maybe it's cause of the problem?

Comment: There are 3 divs that contain the animating faux gifs.  The weird thing is the code works sometimes.  I can't figure out why the page isn't detecting where the page is correctly.